# Ground state of nonlinear Schrodinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stability-theory

Nonlinear Schrodinger equation (NSL) is 
$$
i\phi_t + \Delta \phi + \phi^{2\sigma+1}
$$
I want to show for any $\lambda , \gamma \in \mathbb R$ and $x_0\in \mathbb R^N$,
$$
\psi=\lambda^{1/\sigma}R(\lambda(x+x_0))\exp{i(\lambda^2t +\gamma)}
$$
is a ground state of NSL. The ground state is solution of 
$$
\Delta R -R + R^{2\sigma+1}=0
$$

What I try:
$$
i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=- \lambda^{1/\sigma +2}
\exp(i(\lambda^2 t + \gamma))R(\lambda(x+x_0))  \\
\Delta \psi =\lambda^{1/\sigma +2}
\exp(i(\lambda^2 t + \gamma))\Delta R(\lambda(x+x_0)) \\
\psi^{2\sigma+1} = \lambda^{2+1/\sigma}\exp(i(\lambda^2 t + \gamma)(2\sigma+1))
R^{2\sigma+1}(\lambda(x+x_0))
$$
so 
\begin{align}
i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+
\Delta \psi
+\psi^{2\sigma+1}
&=
\lambda^{1/\sigma +2}\exp(i(\lambda^2 t + \gamma))
(-R+\Delta R + R^{2\sigma +1}\exp(i(\lambda^2t+\gamma))^{2\sigma})
\\
&\ne 0
\end{align}
where is my mistake ?  This question is from the 1.8 of 55th page  of [1].

[1]*Weinstein, Michael I.*, [**Lyapunov stability of ground states of nonlinear dispersive evolution equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160390103), Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 39, 51-67 (1986). [ZBL0594.35005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0594.35005).

Comment: The answer below clears it up, but just to point out one mistake you have done : $(e^{x})^y$ is not $e^{x^y}$ but rather $e^{xy}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schrödinger equation is actually $ i \phi_t + \Delta \phi+|\phi|^{2\sigma}\phi$. When you take the absolute value of $|\psi|^{2\sigma}$, the phase disappears, and so $ i \psi_t + \Delta \psi+|\psi|^{2\sigma}\psi = 0$.